# ForEach on IEnumerable<dynamic> type data

Tags: c#, dynamic, ienumerable

I am getting data in the form of :

```
 [0]: { rkey = "100asb", pkey = "100ap0", ckey = {1/6/2013 3:28:09 AM} }
 [1]: { rkey = "yxq4c", pkey = "100iis", ckey = {1/6/2013 6:38:48 PM} }
  .
  .
  .
```

I have to write another method that has access to the values `rkey`, `pkey` and `ckey`. Unfortunately I can't access them in a linear `ForEach` or `Parallel.ForEach`. I have searched, but I have not found a solution to access my parameters. Some people suggested to convert this to a `Dictionary`, but I am not sure if that is a good path to take. It has to be much simpler than that.

the code that I have written is like this:

```
var films = myrollup.GetCompletedMovies(dtstart, dtend).Result;

using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {

        Parallel.ForEach(films, currentFilm =>
        {
            dynamic f = currentFilm;
            lock (myrollup)
            {
                var user = User.GetAsync(f.pkey).Result;
                var record = new FilmAnalytics()
                {
                    UserID = currentFilm.pkey,
                    FilmID = currentFilm.rkey,
                    UserName = user.FirstName,
                    UserLastName = user.LastName,
                    UserAlias = user.Alias,
                    UserEmail = user.Email,
                    UserFacebook = user.FbEmail,
                    Dateofcompletion = currentFilm.ckey
                };
                session.SaveOrUpdate(record);
            }
        });

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

The variable `films` produces the `IEnumerable<dynamic>` type data.

Comment: can you post the code you've already tried?

Comment: What is preventing you from creating a proper class to hold those values instead of relying upon dynamic?

Comment: You think `dynamic` is simpler than using a `Dictionary`?  This shows that you don't have a proper appreciation for just how much `dynamic` is actually doing and almost certainly shouldn't be using it.

Comment: If you would read my post entirely you could see that I am not suggesting that.

Comment: I agere with Servy. The dynamic keyword should not be used like this. If you have dynamic data - I would suggest you use XML or JSON perhaps.

Comment: what type is `films` collection? `List<dynamic>`?

Comment: Its type is IEnumerable<dynamic>

Comment: can you try something like `var films2 = films.Select(f=>new { rkey = (int)f.rkey }).ToList()`? I.e. first convert your collection to something strongly typed.

Comment: It says the object does not contain a definition for rkey. basically f does not contain a definition for rkey. No progress.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    IEnumerable<dynamic> films = new dynamic[] { new { rkey = 1, rval = "val1" }, new { rkey = 2, rval = "val2" } };

    foreach (var film in films.Select(f => new { RKey = (int)f.rkey,RValue = (string)f.rval }))
        Console.WriteLine(film.RKey + ":" + film.RValue);
}
```

This way I can transform dynamics to strongly typed objects and then I can do whatever I want with them

Comment: I will give this a try and will let you know if it works for my case or not. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class like

```
 public class Thing
    {
        public string rkey { get; set; }
        public string pkey { get; set; }
        public DateTime ckey { get; set; }
    }
```

and then make the task like this:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Thing>> ....
```

then I can have access to pkey, rkey, and ckey.